# Handling exception with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, exception

I have problem with lambda expression. My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Function<String, String> lambda = path -> {
        String result = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result + line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

I'm trying now to make code like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Function<String, String> lambda = path -> {
        String result = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result + line;
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

Is that possible? I can use only java.util.function. I try to delete try catch from "lambda" and my "main" method should be catching that Exception.

Comment: Note that with your first solution you never close the `BufferedRead`, causing a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `Function` class doesn't allow you to throw unchecked exceptions, as you can see from the signature of the [`apply()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-).

You can however easily define your own [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) that does permit exceptions to be thrown, e.g.:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<U,V> {
  public V apply(U u) throws Exception;
}
```

And make your `lambda` variable a `CheckedFunction` instead.

---

The alternative, if you *must* use the built-in `Function` for whatever reason, is to turn all checked exceptions into `RuntimeException`s, e.g.:

```
Function<Foo,Bar> f = foo -> {
  try {
    return foo.methodThatCanThrow();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw e;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
};
```

This will allow your code to compile, but is certainly not a generally recommended best practice.

Comment: "I can only use `java.util.function`"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why? What sort of meaningless restriction is that? You cannot throw exceptions from `java.util.function.Function`, and lambdas are *designed* to support defining your own functional interfaces. If you want to use lambdas the way you're using them in your example code, you'll need to use a different interface.

Comment: Seems you're confusing me with OP.

Answer (score 2):

As dimo414 said, first declare a new [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<U, V> {
    public V apply(U u) throws IOException;
}
```

Then I'll go one step further by refactoring the lambda expression into the following:

```
CheckedFunction<String, String> lambda = path -> {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
                return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            }
        };
```

The [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) takes care of closing the `BufferedRead` in any case and using the conciseness of the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to concatenate all the lines.

Going a second step further, you don't even need to bother with `BufferedReader` anymore if you use `Files` ! This can be taken down to the following lambda:

```
CheckedFunction<String, String> lambda = path -> Files.lines(Paths.get(path)).collect(Collectors.joining());
```